# My ruby while loop does not give me any output as an array of numbers

Tags: ruby

the loop is aiming at extracting which numbers in an array ( allergy_values ) will return a sum equal to user's input number ( score ) and puts them in an array ( arr ); however, after inputting the score, the program outputs just the score to the screen and does not create the array.

```rb
allergy={"eggs"=>1,"peanuts"=>2,"shellfish"=>4,"strawberries"=>8,"tomatoes"=>16,"chocolate"=>32,"pollen"=>64,"cats"=>128}
puts "Enter your allergy test score: "
print "> "
score = gets.strip.to_i
allergy_values = allergy.values.reverse
allergy_finder = allergy.invert
arr = []
allergy_list = []
i = 0
while i>=0 && i<allergy_values.size
    if score - allergy_values[i]>0
      arr.push(allergy_values[i])
      score = score - allergy_values[i]
      i+=1
      next
    elsif score - allergy_values[i]== 0
      arr.push(allergy_values[i])
      exit
    else
      i+=1
      next
    end
end
p arr
```

Comment: It does create the array, it simply doesn't do anything with it. JFYI, `exit` terminates the program. Did you mean to use `break` instead?

Comment: Yes, I replaced exit with break and program worked well, Thanks Sergio